# Unlock and then immediately lock mutex/semaphore. Bad practice or is there a way to do it?

Tags: c, semaphore

I have been learning multiprocessing lately and I have run into the scenario where I am done working with a resource, and I need someone else to use it before I need it again, but I have nothing else to do between releasing it and taking it again :

(pseudo code)

```
while (true) {
    mutex_lock(resource);
        /* modify resource */
    mutex_unlock(resource);
        /* wait for someone else to modify resource */
}
```

the issue is that this process will unlock the resource and then immediately lock it again, even if there is another process blocked.
I can only assume this is because it just never gives up the CPU.

Is what I'm doing bad practice? I don't see ways around it except designing code specifically around this issue. Is there a way to `yield` the processor in C/C++ so that I can guarantee I don't get the lock again?

Comment: if you have a bunch of threads all waiting on the same lock, once one thread unlocks, all of the other threads that are waiting on the lock will be ahead of the thread that just unlocked.  So, this behavior is ok. server with

Comment: Typically a `sleep(0)` does that - yields to the operating system, renouncing in line of principle to the rest of the time quantum if the operating system finds anything better to do.

Comment: Are you using the `pthread` API?

Comment: In this case, I'm using multiple processes with `fork` and system V semaphores, but I had the same problem when using `pthread`s another time

Comment: This sounds like a case for using a condition variable, not just a plain mutex. You wait on the condition, when someone else modifies the resource, they notify on the condition, so you don't spend your time spin looping on something when it isn't changing.

Comment: @ShadowRanger that makes sense, I think I'll give that a go. Thanks!

Comment: @ShadowRanger: You should make that an answer and maybe show a quick example of how to do it. Note: it's shorter than OP's code now with the explicit unlock/lock.

Comment: @bruceg: There is no guarantee that the threads will acquire the mutex in any particular order. The unlocking thread has a pretty good chance of reacquiring the mutex it has just unlocked ahead of the threads already waiting.

Comment: Sleep(0) appears to have worked, ran it for a prolonged period of time and never had lock issues

Comment: @EOF you're right.  There's no guarantee.  Best to use a real priority queue if you want that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use a signal that will block your looping thread until your signal is triggered by a different thread.
Using this concept you won't burn through CPU cycles and instead will only act when you need to.
In C# this can take the form of a syntactically sweetened Semaphore (AutoResetEvent) however in C you will need to go a little deeper.

Have a look at: https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/locks-mutexes-semaphores.html
It will remind you of the purpose of each breed of thread-protection device.

Good Luck!

Comment: Signals are heavy-weight and rather fraught with problems.  There are better ways to do it, such as `pthread_cond_wait()` with a condition variable.

Answer (score 0):

It always seems to make sense to the modification of variables shared across threads in mutexes to protect them. While this achieve protecting those variables it doesn't syncronise access to those variables.

There isn't really a set way to do it other than to understand exactly how threads work and how the locks you're using work.

Perhaps it's more misleading that people often say it's a good practice to lock as little as possible for performance. That might seem like only locking the variable shared between threads but in reality that might not be sufficient.

What that means in this context is that your code which is a consumer doesn't have a sure fire wait to know when another thread has modified the data. Unlock doesn't sit around and wait for someone to lock it.

```
mutex m
string in

void producer()
    while(true)
        STDIN.blockingWaitForReadable()
        m.lock()
        in = STDIN.readNonBlock()
        m.unlock()

void consumer()
    while(true)
        m.lock()
        if isNull(s)
            m.unlock()
            continue
        out = in
        in = null
        m.unlock()
        STDOUT.writeNonBlockBecauseItsBufferred(out)

run(producer)
run(consumer)
```

All this does is to ensure that the code in the lock and unlock seconds doesn't run concurrently. While this succeeds in ensuring only one thread has access at a time to the variable in, it doesn't syncronise them. More is needed than to simply naively wrap a variable shared across threads with a mutex. You also need to consider if a thread is waiting for another thread to do something with that data.

Otherwise a lot of unpleasant things can happen. In this case if no one writes to STDIN, consumer will run as an infinite loop using 100% CPU. It will just lock, check that s is null and then unlock over and over.

There's also no telling when the consumer thread will run. It might be delayed for some reason. That means it'll be possible for the producer to overwrite the previous string. If you add an isNull check to producer then you only end up using 100% CPU there as well when it has something to read from STDIN but the consumer hasn't yet consumer s from the previous read.

Appending to the string in the producer will protect you from the data integrity issue where otherwise you would lose arbitrary strings.

What you really want here is for the consumer to be waiting until there is string data and then processing it. After that it should wait again.

A simple example:

```
mutex m
string in
thread c

void producer()
    while(true)
        STDIN.blockingWaitForReadable()
        m.lock()
        in = STDIN.readNonBlock()
        c.wake()
        m.unlock()

void consumer()
    while(true)
        sleep()
        m.lock()
        if isNull(in)
            m.unlock()
            continue
        out = in
        in = null
        m.unlock()
        STDOUT.writeBlocking(out)

run(producer)
c = run(consumer)
```

Even this might not be perfect, as c.wake can be called while consumer is not sleeping though it tends get us much closer to something that wont waste huge amounts of CPU.

Your mutex library should include some signalling mechanism for syncronisation, failing that your threading library should provide something for it.

Lock will only block when something else has it locked. Otherwise it will return immediately. Both of these threads are only locked part time which is something to consider.